# Is is possible to change line color in highchart xy plot for specific y range only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I wonder is it possible to change line color in highchart for specific y range using some kind of function, I really don't know how to achieve this, this is my idea, as a beginner I don't know how to write function to do this, function which I want to develop would like this

Added in fiddle have a look [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vAM9d/)

```
function range(ystart,yend,ycolor,xpoint){

// I do not know how to achieve this,
// I am interested send y range as a argument suppose in current example
// y : 1 - 6 should be in red color and
// x = 36 should have marker in yellow color

// So I would like to call like this 
range(1,6,"#F90B0B",34)
}
```

This is actual code

```
$(function () {
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        zoomType: 'xy',
        type : 'scatter',
        marginLeft: 50,
        marginBottom: 90
    },

    yAxis: {
        reversed: true,

    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
                  animation: {
                               duration: 2000
                             },
                  lineWidth: 2
                },
    },
    xAxis: {
        opposite: true  
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Test Plot',
        data: [
            [28, 0],
            [29,1],
            [30, 3],
            [34, 4],
            [32,5],
            [28, 6],
            [24, 7],
            [19,8],
            [15, 9]
        ]
    }]
});
```

});

Thank in advance for all volunteers

Comment: The line plotted in such a chart is a single SVG element, and can have only one color.  Your options for multiple colors require either multiple series (as indicated in the answer from Abdullah Tayyab), or adding additional SVG elements to cover the portion of the existing line element with a second of the desired color.

You won't be able to simply change the color of the portion you want to be different.

Comment: take a look on http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/stacking/index.html. it can help you i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this moment is it not supported, only by two series, but in the nearest feature it should be available.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to separate the data and create separate series (with different colors) for the different ranges. That would mean, of course, that you would have to create a custom legend.

Edit to your function:

```
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            zoomType: 'xy',
            type : 'scatter',
            marginLeft: 50,
            marginBottom: 90
        },

        yAxis: {
            reversed: true,

        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                      animation: {
                                   duration: 2000
                                 },
                      lineWidth: 2
                    },
        },
        xAxis: {
            opposite: true  
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Test Plot',
            data: [
                [28, 0],
                [29,1],
                [30, 3],
                [34, 4],
                [32,5],
                [28, 6]
            ],
            color: "#F90B0B"
        },
               {
            name: 'Test Plot2',
            data: [
                [28, 6],
                [24, 7],
                [19,8],
                [15, 9]
            ],
                   color: "#F909F9"
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: I know this method, but its not my aim. my aim to create function

Comment: "create function" is about as vague as you could get. 
Anything can be wrapped in a function.